# How can I define username and password in the URL connection string?

Tags: java, oracle

All I have read in oracle doc is that I can replace this:

```
OracleDataSource ods = new OracleDataSource();
ods.setDriverType("thin");
ods.setServerName("localhost");
ods.setNetworkProtocol("tcp");
ods.setDatabaseName("databaseName");
ods.setPortNumber(1521);
ods.setUser("userName");
ods.setPassword("Password");
```

by this:

```
ods.setUser("userName");
ods.setPassword("Password");
ods.setURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ENABLE=broken)(LOAD_BALANCE = yes)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=dedicated)(SERVICE_NAME=xxxx)(FAILOVER_MODE =(TYPE = SELECT)(METHOD = BASIC)(RETRIES = 10)(DELAY = 1))))");
```

But I am wondering whether is possible include everything in one string to store all together in a config file or not, i.e., everything set with *ods.setURL()*.

Comment: Yes, it can - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/urls.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ods.setURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:userName/Password@(DESCRIPTION=(ENABLE=broken)(LOAD_BALANCE = yes)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=dedicated)(SERVICE_NAME=xxxx)(FAILOVER_MODE =(TYPE = SELECT)(METHOD = BASIC)(RETRIES = 10)(DELAY = 1))))");
```